# non-indentation of the second line of bibliograpy

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, indentation

I would like to print my references part non-indented. I have found information regarding how to indent bib items, but not regarding my problem. I am trying to have the second line of references non-indented as obeying the margin restrictions of the rest of my document which are provided by `\geometry{verbose,tmargin=1.25in,bmargin=1.25in,lmargin=1.4in,rmargin=1.15in}` command. 'bibliography' file includes my references. Thanks very much in advance! Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[letterpaper]{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=1.25in,bmargin=1.25in,
lmargin=1.4in,rmargin=1.15in}
\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{indentfirst}

\begin{document}
Text goes here. ..\cite{ito92, joannopoulos95}
Here, n describes the increase in P1 by nucleation. The gain
($gP_{L-1}$) and loss ($-P_{L}$) terms are due to subunit addition.

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{references}

\end{document}
```

The compiled file is [image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://tex.stackexchange.com/tour). Now your MWE does not show the problem. Also, it should be _minimal_, so all those packages seem a bit too many. Can you remove them? I suggest using `lipsum` or `blindtext` for filler text, and adding some kind of bibliography, instead of a lot of `\include`s which clearly cannot be of use.

Comment: Is the latexindent tag appropriate here?

Comment: @cmhughes I'm no expert but it sure seems suitable :).

Comment: Though learning it is a package and is not called in the MWE I might rethink that… perhaps it could help? @EsmaEryilmaz

Comment: @cmhughes you wouldn't be the Chris Hughes who wrote `latexindent.pl` as the `manual.pdf` says, would you :)?

Comment: @MickG, my apologies..The code is edited now.

Comment: @EsmaEryilmaz apart from correcting the indentation, you should include some bibliography, at least the two citations you make in the document.

Comment: For example, I added [this totally invented bibliography](http://i.stack.imgur.com/40hQf.png), compiled, and got [text](http://i.stack.imgur.com/to8Ov.png) and [bib](http://i.stack.imgur.com/fF5Y0.png). What you want is to have the second line aligned with the numbers ([1] [2] etc) rather than the start of the first line (Foo Bar Baz), right? This info belongs in the question.

Comment: @MickG, yes that is correct. In another saying I want to have the second line starting from the left margin which is 1.4 in.

Comment: Yep, I'm the author of latexindent :) this question seems to be about output, so I don't think that the latexindent is appropriate :)

Comment: Indeed it is about output. I have managed to get your desired result, @EsmaEryilmaz, but my code breaks as soon as there are 10 bib items, because the label is moved slightly to the left due to its width.

Comment: [Here is what I mean](http://i.stack.imgur.com/uedWG.png).

Comment: Nailed it. Answering in a sec.

Comment: @MickG, thank you! It seems that you solved my problem. Your second line starts with the ref numbers in case of your 1st reference. Could you please share with me what you have changed/added?

Comment: @EsmaEryilmaz see the answer below, and you're welcome :). Apparently, it took me 8 mins to write up that answer :).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note: this is VERY hacky. Perhaps there is a smarter way to do this. Anyway:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[letterpaper]{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=1.25in,bmargin=1.25in,
lmargin=1.4in,rmargin=1.15in}
\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]
     {\chapter*{\bibname}%
      \setbox2\hbox{\@biblabel{#1}}
      \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\bibname}{\MakeUppercase\bibname}%
      \begin{enumerate}[itemindent=!,leftmargin=0pt,label={\@biblabel{\@arabic\c@enumiv}\setbox2\hbox{\@biblabel{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}\hspace{\labelwidth}\hspace{-\wd2}},labelwidth=\wd2]
            \usecounter{enumiv}%
      \sloppy
      \clubpenalty4000
      \@clubpenalty \clubpenalty
      \widowpenalty4000%
      \sfcode`\.\@m}
     {\def\@noitemerr
       {\@latex@warning{Empty `thebibliography' environment}}%
      \end{enumerate}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Text goes here. ..\cite{ito92, joannopoulos95}

Here, n describes the increase in P1 by nucleation. The gain ($gP_{L-1}$) and loss ($-P_{L}$) terms are due to subunit addition.

\bibliographystyle{unsrt} \bibliography{references}

\begin{thebibliography}{11}
\bibitem{ito92}
Foo Bar Baz,
\emph{Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amet},
Consectetuer editions,
March 24th, 1993,
Rivendell.
\bibitem{mu}
qef
\bibitem{2424}
oihoiwrgh
\bibitem{qeqefqe}
3t31tsef
\bibitem{214}
qeeqfr
\bibitem{1235689}
12345678900987654321
\bibitem{3215}
asdsad
\bibitem{124124}
14124124
\bibitem{134134}
adgvadagd
\bibitem{foobarbazbellheisenbug}
Schrodinbug Heisenbug Schrodinbug Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer adipiscing elit foobar
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

I redefined the bibliography environment to use an `enumerate` environment from `enumitem`, and fiddling with the parameters I managed to get the desired result. Many pieces of code are copied off the definition of the bibliography environment taken from `report`. My edits are in the part from `\setbox1` to `\usecounter`. There, I set box 1 to `\@biblabel{#1}` which is the correct label width as was previously set by the class. `\@mkboth` is off the class. Then we have the list. THe options `itemindent` and `leftmargin` are set as suggested by "Original answer" [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/168370/42315), so thank karlkoeller for that. `label=` is sorf of copied off the class, though the `\hspace` is what solved the problem in the comment's screenshot, or rather the variant where [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ofs6N.png) was a bit to the right of the left margin: basically it places exactly enough space to align the [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ofs6N.png) with the second line. `labelwidth=` takes the width of box 1 at the moment of the list's start (so box 1 is what was set by `\setbox1`) as its value. So the label width is, in this case, [10]'s width, but when the label would be tighter it is not flushed right but an `\hspace` is inserted that gets it exactly aligned on the left. Here is the output:

[image]

Is that it?

---

#### Simplified version still using `enumitem`

Change the code between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` with

```
\makeatletter
\newlength\biblabelwd
\renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]
 {\chapter*{\bibname}%
  \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\bibname}{\MakeUppercase\bibname}%
  \settowidth\biblabelwd{\@biblabel{#1} }%
  \begin{enumerate}[
    itemindent=\biblabelwd,
    leftmargin=0pt,
    label={\makebox[\biblabelwd][l]{\@biblabel{\arabic{enumiv}}}},
    labelwidth=0pt,
    labelsep=0pt
  ]
  \usecounter{enumiv}%
  \sloppy
  \clubpenalty4000
  \@clubpenalty \clubpenalty
  \widowpenalty4000%
  \sfcode`\.\@m}
 {\def\@noitemerr
  {\@latex@warning{Empty `thebibliography' environment}}%
  \end{enumerate}}
\makeatother
```

Comment: You shouldn't be using `\box1`, but `\box2`. Odd numbered scratch registers should be used only for global assignments.

Comment: @egreg whoops I got odd and even mixed up, I thought odd = local and even = global :).

Comment: I found an easier way to set the parameters; since it's just a variation of your method, I think the best thing is to make an edit.