# Bibliography from second line on aligned left with no indent

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, indentation

I would like to have my bibliography printed from the second line on aligned left so the text is in the the normal margin restriction, like here:
[image]
The solution [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/275597/non-indentation-of-the-second-line-of-bibliograpy) provides only a very complicated redefinition. Is there a way to achieve this while using `\bibliography{filename}`?
Using `\hspace*{\labelwidth}`works only partially.

```
\begin{filecontents}{bibfile.bib}
    @ARTICLE{Abernethy2003,
        author = {Colin D. Abernethy and Gareth M. Codd and Mark D. Spicer
            and Michelle K. Taylor},
        title = {{A} highly stable {N}-heterocyclic carbene complex of
            trichloro-oxo-vanadium(\textsc{v}) displaying novel
            {C}-{C}(carbene) bonding interactions},
        journal = {{J}. {A}m. {C}hem. {S}oc.},
        year = {2003},
        volume = {125},
        pages = {1128--1129},
        number = {5},
        doi = {10.1021/ja0276321},
    }
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[twocolumn,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\usepackage[super]{natbib}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@biblabel[1]{\hspace*{\labelwidth}(#1)}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

    Text and some more text.\cite{Abernethy2003}

    \bibliography{bibfile}
    \bibliographystyle{biochem}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `\@bibsetup`:

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@ARTICLE{Abernethy2003,
  author = {Colin D. Abernethy and Gareth M. Codd and Mark D. Spicer
            and Michelle K. Taylor},
  title = {A highly stable {N}-heterocyclic carbene complex of
            trichloro-oxo-vanadium(\textsc{v}) displaying novel
            {C}-{C}(carbene) bonding interactions},
  journal = {J. Am. Chem. Soc.},
  year = {2003},
  volume = {125},
  pages = {1128--1129},
  number = {5},
  doi = {10.1021/ja0276321},
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[twocolumn,10pt]{article}

\usepackage[super]{natbib}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@biblabel}[1]{(#1)}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \renewcommand\@bibsetup[1]{%
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{0pt}%
    \setlength{\itemindent}{2.5em}%
    \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibsep}%
    \setlength{\parsep}{\z@}%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Text and some more text.\cite{Abernethy2003}

\bibliographystyle{biochem}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

[image]