# No indentation in non-second lines of bibliography list

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, xetex

dear experts!

My setting is: *XeLaTeX* compiler, *biblatex* package for bibliography and document class is *extarticle*.
I`m trying to achieve this style of indentation in my bibliography list:[image]

As you can see, I need the first line to be indented (I have solution for this), while the other lines should not be indented. I tried solution from this topic...

> [non-indentation of the second line of bibliograpy](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/275597/non-indentation-of-the-second-line-of-bibliograpy)

...but that doesn't helped me. I don't know what is the problem with that solution.

Here is my .tex code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage[sorting=none]{biblatex} %Imports biblatex package
\usepackage{enumitem}

\addbibresource{sample.bib} %Import the bibliography file

\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{\hspace{9mm}#1.\hspace{-7pt}}
\setlength\bibitemsep{0mm}

\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]
     {\chapter*{\bibname}%
      \setbox2\hbox{\@biblabel{#1}}
      \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\bibname}{\MakeUppercase\bibname}%
      \begin{enumerate}[itemindent=!,leftmargin=0pt,label={\@biblabel{\@arabic\c@enumiv}\setbox2\hbox{\@biblabel{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}\hspace{\labelwidth}\hspace{-1mm}},labelwidth=1mm]
            \usecounter{enumiv}%
      \sloppy
      \clubpenalty4000
      \@clubpenalty \clubpenalty
      \widowpenalty4000%
      \sfcode`\.\@m}
     {\def\@noitemerr
       {\@latex@warning{Empty `thebibliography' environment}}%
      \end{enumerate}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Lets put some links in text. For example \cite{LINK1}. Secondly, this is another link \cite{LINK2}.

\printbibliography %Prints bibliography

\end{document}
```

And my .bib file is like:

```
@misc{LINK1,
    note   = "A. J. Krasznahorkay et al. Observation of anomalous internal pair creation in $\mathrm{^8Be}$: a possible indication of a light, neutral boson. Phys. Rev. Lett. PRL 116, 042501 (2016)"
}

@misc{LINK2,
    note   = "George D. Greenwade The {C}omprehensive {T}ex {A}rchive {N}etwork ({CTAN}) (2013)"
}
```

Could you please suggest any other solutions for my goal or propose some problems that I`ve probably missed?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: @Zarko, thank you! Hello.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer you found is for BibTeX, but you are using `biblatex`, which completely reimplements citations and bibliographies and does not use `thebibliography`.

You could try

```
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage[sorting=none]{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{#1\adddot}
\setlength{\biblabelsep}{\labelsep}
\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\list
     {\printtext[labelnumberwidth]{%
        \printfield{labelprefix}%
        \printfield{labelnumber}}}
     {\setlength{\labelwidth}{-\labelnumberwidth}%
      \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{0pt}%
      \setlength{\itemindent}{\bibhang}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}%
      \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{\hss##1}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lets put some links in text. For example \cite{sigfridsson}.
Secondly, this is another link \cite{worman}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Bibliography with first line indented, subsequent lines not.]

You may want to look into using `gost-numeric` of [`biblatex-gost`](https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-gost). That comes closer to the overall bibliography style you show in the image.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage[style=gost-numeric]{biblatex}

\setlength{\biblabelsep}{\labelsep}
\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\list
     {\printtext[labelnumberwidth]{%
        \printfield{labelprefix}%
        \printfield{labelnumber}}}
     {\setlength{\labelwidth}{-\labelnumberwidth}%
      \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{0pt}%
      \setlength{\itemindent}{\bibhang}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}%
      \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{\hss##1}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lets put some links in text. For example \cite{sigfridsson}.
Secondly, this is another link \cite{worman}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: GOST-style bibliography with first line indented]

The `.bib` entries in the question with all data in the `note` entry look a bit like an attempt to manually control the bibliography style. This is against the spirit of BibTeX and `biblatex`, where the idea is that you'd give the data in semantically useful fields and let the style figure out how to typeset things.

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing out with this problem. It works as I needed.
Yes, entries in .bib is actually attempt to manually control style. It is confusing me too, but I`ve done this for two reasons: 1) I have some specific requirements for my work (it is bachelor diploma in russian university), 2) It is my first experience of using bibliography in TeX and I have no enough time right now to find suitable style in the very broad list. So it is just temporary and ugly solution that I found)