# How to indent enumerate at the left of its label

Tags: enumerate

When my label is too big, it leaves the page. How to indent with the left of label or simply increase left alignment.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{enumerate} %package for enumerate
\usepackage{enumitem} %package for enumerate
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=Very big word that leaves the page \roman*]
\item item
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: See this answer by Jesse  in Indenting in enumerate (TeX/LaTeX) http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/168375/89976

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2):

Don't use both `enumerate` and `enumitem`. Note optional arguments are between bracket (`[ ]`), not between `\[ \]` (which is for displayed equations).

The trick for your problem is to use  left-aligned labels (default is right aligned):

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{enumitem} %package for enumerate

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=Very big word that leaves the page \roman*, align = left]
\item A first item.
\item A longer item. A longer item. A longer item. A longer item. A longer item. A longer item. A longer item. A longer item.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add `leftmargin=*`

```
  [![\documentclass\[11pt,a4paper\]{report}
    \usepackage{enumerate} 
    \usepackage{enumitem} 
    \begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}\[label=Very big word that leaves the page \roman*,leftmargin=*\]
    \item item
    \end{enumerate}
    \end{document}][1]][1]
```

[image]